# How to tell PHP Storm that the function return static or another type

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpdoc

```
class A {
    /**
     * @return static|bool
     */
    public static function build()
    {
         if (/**/) {
             return new static;
         }

         return false;
    }
}

class B extends A {}

$o = B::build();
```

PHP Storm does not understand that there is the B instance in $o.
If I leave just the `static` without second type in `return` annotation, all is right.

Comment: because function `build` is defined in `A` not in `B`

Comment: Yes but this is the late static binding and there will be the B instance

Comment: you should find the late class name, then fetch its static value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment PhpStorm does not correctly understand `@return static|bool` -- only `@return static` on its own is working right now.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-23435 -- watch this and related ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on progress.

---

Partial workaround: type hint that variable (`$o` in your case) via inlline PHPDoc, e.g.

```
/** @var B $o */
$o = B::build();
```

Answer (score 0):

a workaround, not very elegant:

```
 class A {
     protected $class_name;
     public static function build()
     {
          return $class_name::static_variable;
     }
}

 class B extends A {
      protected $class_name="B";
 }

$o = B::build();
```